# Obtaining branches

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts, branching-rules

I'm reading the Ahlfors book of Complex Variable, and I don't understand how to obtain one branch of a single-valued function. Can someone explain me how to do this in a way more extensive for any given function?